# Instantiate UITextField delegate programmatically?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitextfield

I have a `UITextField` that has been added to my view in Interface Builder. My question is: is there a way I can programatically set its delegate from within Xcode? I know that I can connect up the delegate in IB by dragging a connection from `UITextField>Delegate` to my viewController which implements `textFieldShouldReturn:`

Just curious as the control "UITextField" is obviously instantiated in IB and not directly through code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've got an IBOutlet to it, just use:

```
[theTextField setDelegate:aDelegate];
```

Comment: Thank you, I did have an IBOutlet so thats just what I needed. Just a side note to anyone else I also needed to conform my interface to the UITextFieldDelegate protocol. It looks like you don't need that if you do the linking in IB.